# using regular expression in list.files of R function

Tags: regex, r

I want to use list.files of R to list files containing this pattern "un[a digit]" such as filename_un1.txt, filename_un2.txt etc... Here is the general code:

```
list_files <- list.files(path="my_file_path", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "here I need help", full.names = TRUE)
```

I have tried putting `un\d` in the pattern input but does not work.

Comment: Try `pattern = "_un\\d+\\.txt$"`

Comment: To elaborate, you need to escape the backslash.

Comment: Or simply `'un\\d+'`

Comment: @ Gopala according to http://regexone.com/, \d match any number. So why it needs two \\ here? Also, what is the + for? Thanks.

Comment: @kelvinfrog: Do you want to say `un\\d` is enough for you?

Comment: See my answer, feel free to adjust as needed.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew you are right. "un\\d+" is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_files <- list.files(path="my_file_path", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "un[0-9]", full.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should bear in mind that in R, strings allow using escape sequences. However, the regex engine needs a literal `\` to pass shorthand character classes (like `\d` for digits) or to escape special chars (like `\\.` to match a literal dot.)

So, you need

```
pattern = "_un\\d+\\.txt$"
```

where

- `_un` - matches a literal substring `_un`
- `\\d+` - matches 1 or more digits (as `+` is a *one or more* quantifier)
- `\\.` - matches a literal dot
- `txt` - matches a literal sequence of characters `txt`
- `$` - end of string.